# Copy and paste features or append shapefile - qGis python

Tags: python, qgis

I need to join two polygon files into a single, without creating a new file.

In Arcgis this is called ***append*** tool, however does not exist in qgis

Comment: There are thousands of Q&As about QGIS at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

It's just to do:

1. select your features in the "from" layer
2. copy them with CTRL C (or icon)
3. enable editing mode in the "to" layer
4. paste them with CTRL V (or icon)